# Lower Keyboard sensitivity in java keyhandler?

Tags: java, events, key, awt, keyevent

```
private class KeyHandler implements KeyEventDispatcher{

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            tetrominoList.get(currentPiece).moveRight();
    }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        tetrominoList.get(currentPiece).moveLeft();
    }else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        System.out.print("k");
        tetrominoList.get(currentPiece).rotate();
    }


        return false;
    }
```

this code returns "kk" when I press the up arrow once. How can I configure java or my computer so it only register one key hit instead of two?

EDIT: This is my temporary solution

```
    private class KeyHandler implements KeyEventDispatcher{

    int counter = 0;
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            tetrominoList.get(currentPiece).moveRight();
    }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        tetrominoList.get(currentPiece).moveLeft();
    }else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        counter++;
        if(counter == 2){
            System.out.print("k");
            tetrominoList.get(currentPiece).rotate();
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your solution seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but looks like your code processes both `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED` events. Probably you should check for a `KEY_TYPED` event and once that happens print your letter. Otherwise you can process only one of the first two events.

Comment: +1, but keyTyped events are not generated for up/down/right/left etc.. KeyEvents. Just check for keyPressed events.  However the better solution is to use `Key Bindings`. Search the forum for more information. This suggestion is made daily.

Comment: @camickr, didn't pay attention that it was about arrows. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @user67784,  If the bindings don't work then you didn't implement them properly. The code you posted here doesn't work properly either. Why didn't you ask for help with Key Bindings since this is the proper way to solve the problem?